# Python3 adding the last octet of an IP address

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm parsing a file and one of the columns is the subnet for example 192.168.0.0/24. 
I would like to take that subnet and just add 3 to the last octet and with the end result of 192.168.0.3 without the /24. 
I was able to open the file for reading, split it into ',' locate the subnet and add but I can't produce 192.168.0.3 I only produce 3.

```
import re

file=open('/home/lab01/clients/a/2018/automation/Production_VRF','r')
for items in file:
 _gw=(items.split(',')[2])
 Var6=re.split(r'[./]',_gw)
 Var7=(Var6[3])
 vip=sum=int(Var7)+3
 print(vip)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the concatenation of the first 3 elements in Var6 and the value that you have obtined:

```
ip = Var6[0]+"."+Var6[1]+"."+Var6[2]+"."+str(vip)
```

Comment: Yes this makes total sense and all the elements are there to take advantage of. Simple and easy!